# Glassfish 3.1.2 UTF-8 Encoding error

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, jvm, glassfish-3

I'm facing encoding problem with latest version of **Glassfish (3.1.2)**. I have no problem with Tomcat, I'm using Spring, so I've already added Character Encoding Filters and also another encoding filter to force encoding at requests and responses with content-type.

**I've added these properties into JVM Settings at Glassfish Web Console:**

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-DuriEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved by character adding encoding parameter at the end of the `jdbcUrl` like this:

```
http://dbserver:xxxx/myDB?characterEncoding=utf-8
```